# How do i detect fields or columns in a mysql database that has been updated?

Tags: php, mysql, updates

I am developing an application using MVC concept and I want to maintain a table which keeps record of the columns from different tables that have been updated.

this is the query in my controller:

```
if(!$error) {
    $NAME           = $_POST["NAME"];
    $FNAME          = $_POST["FNAME"];
    $SNAME          = $_POST["SNAME"];
    $DNAME          = $_POST["DNAME"];
    $DOB            = $_POST["DOB"];
    $IDMARK         = $_POST["IDMARK"];
    $ES1NAME        = $_POST["ES1NAME"];
    $ES2NAME        = $_POST["ES2NAME"];
    $LANG1          = $_POST["LANG1"];
    $LANG2          = $_POST["LANG2"];
    $MATHS          = $_POST["MATHS"];
    $SS             = $_POST["SS"];
    $SCIENCE        = $_POST["SCIENCE"];


    $table = $_POST['table'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $queryStr = mysql_query("UPDATE db_parent.$table SET NAME = '$NAME', FNAME = '$FNAME', SNAME = '$SNAME', DNAME = '$DNAME', DOB = '$DOB', IDMARK = '$IDMARK', ES1NAME = '$ES1NAME', ES2NAME = '$ES2NAME', LANG1 = '$LANG1', LANG2 = $LANG2, MATHS = '$MATHS', SS = '$SS', SCIENCE = '$SCIENCE'  WHERE ID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());

    $queryUpdate= mysql_fetch_array($queryStr);

    sys_url::redirect(sys_url::site("Department/childDepartment/Update?id=$id&table=$table"));

    return;
}
```

This is the form :

```
<form id = "form" name = "myForm" method = "POST" onsubmit = "" action = "<?= sys_url::site('Department/childDepartment/Update?id='.$_GET['id'].'&table='.$_GET['table'])?>" >
    <div class="row" >
        <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "<?= $_GET['id']; ?>" >
        <input type = "hidden" name = "table" value = "<?= $_GET['table']; ?>" >
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6" >
            <label align = "left" > Name :</label >
            <div class="form-group" >
                <input class="form-control" name = "NAME" value = "<?= $student['NAME'] ?>" >
            </div >
        </div >
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6" >
            <label align = "left" > Father's Name :</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="FNAME" value="<?= $student['FNAME'] ?>" >
            </div>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" value="1" name="search" class="btn btn-primary">UPDATE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The form will edit and update the fields. I have another updates_table that I would like to record which columns from which tables have been updated. I don't want to keep record of whole rows as that would overpopulate the database later on. How do I do it? I read somewhere about triggers and column_update() but I am not sure if I understood it properly. Thank you for all the support.

Comment: It's 2018. You really should be using PDO or mysqli and prepared statements.

Comment: ok.. how do we do that in php7 and above??

Comment: If you are on php 7, this code should not work at all as the `mysql_*` functions have been removed :-) Anyway, you should start with the manual, for example: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: actually the project i'm working on is an old one using php5... we don't have the green signal to upgrade it to php7 yet..and i have this update module to finish up within the month so i gotta work with this version... any solutions??

Comment: @RongsenTzudir Please edit your question to include the source codes you have tried and the results (or error messages) you get.

Comment: You simply can't upgrade to PHP 7 until you eliminate all these `mysql_query` calls. Since this code is absolutely riddled with **EXTREMELY DANGEROUS SQL INJECTION BUGS** that's something you should do on an **IMMEDIATE BASIS**. If this is a public-facing site it would take seconds to crack it wide open. I cannot stress how vulnerable this code is, your entire business could implode at any instant because of it.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: @tadman yes.. i have changed the code and used certain validation functions to escape before storing the values from the form coming through $_POST to prevent sql injection. like so, $NAME    = validate_data($_POST["NAME"]);

Comment: That's still not enough. Virtually every `validate_data` function I've seen does it wrong, and more importantly, can be omitted by accident, leaving you wide open. Prepared statements with placeholder values are the only way to be absolutely sure you're doing it correctly. Everything else has an element of risk that means you must be extremely disciplined. A single injection hole can take down your entire site.

Comment: i'll keep that in mind .. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your responses... anyways, i got the solution to the issue.

I used an array to store the old data from the database by calling a SELECT query before running the UPDATE query. And then the new data coming from the form is compared to the old data in the array  one by one using a foreach loop. If the incoming data is same as the existing data then it is skipped. if not then i use another update query to update the table with the new data.